# Different file contents for two applications

Tags: windows, 64-bit, filesystems

I have a file located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm\cntlm.ini`.

There are two users, lets call them `A` and `B` (`B` being an administrator). Both users have read permissions for this file.

If I open this file in Notepad++, it shows different file contents to when I open it with Windows Notepad.

If I open Command Prompt as user `A` and run:

```
type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm\cntlm.ini"
```

I'll get one set of contents. Then if I run:

```
cat "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm\cntlm.ini"
```

I'll get different contents. If I do the same with user `B`, the file contents are the same for both programs (same as using `type` with user `A`).

The pattern seems to be that third party applications show a different file when running as user `A`, and the same file when running as user `B`.

How is it possible for two files to exist at the same path? Is this an issue with 64-bit vs 32-bit applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Vista/7/8 will redirect save attempts from UAC-unaware editors or limited users to the Virtual Store. On User A, explore to `C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME-HERE\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm` and see if there is a `cntlm.ini` file there. This is a likely cause of the discrepancy. Deleting it from the virtual store should resolve the discrepancy.